# How to change page logo

Tags: html, favicon

I'm a beginner in web development so that I'm trying to create and publish my first project on the internet. The problem exists when I search my web's name on the google search box and see its logo doesn't change as I expected.  [As you can see that the logo is a blue globe but i want it to be like the logo in the second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Eef9.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK6x1.png)

Comment: Do you have your **favicon** set up correctly? https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/239343578/favicon-for-website-is-not-showing-up-on-google-search Also read: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/favicon-in-search - Anyways, do an extensive research.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 1):

The image you are referring to is a favicon. It can be set by adding the code below within your `<head>` tag:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/image-filename.ico">
```